# Detect TextView clipping and trim

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

The problem I am trying to solve is slightly different than other problems I have seen on stackoverflow (ex: [detect clipping in android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563785/detect-clipping-in-android-textview)), and I don't know if it's easily achievable.

What I would like to do is as follows...

Inside of a `TextView` with hardcoded dp width and height, I would like to only show as much of a string in the TextView as possible without the last line clipping. If the last line is clipping then I would like to trim off everything including that line to the end of the string (or at least not display it). If the string is short enough, and can fit in without trimming then everything is fine, and nothing needs to be done.

I would like to keep the `text_size` the same, which is something that other people seem to want to reduce in size in order to display all of their string, but keeping the `text_size` the same is more important to me.

Comment: Relevant other post I made, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240131/textview-ellipsize-height-wise.