# TextView ellipsize height wise

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Is there any equivalent of `android:ellipsize` (which ellipsizes text that is too long on the x-axis) for text that is too long on the y-axis? I have a TextView which must be a fixed height, however the text inside of it is usually too long to all fit in, and I would like it to stop before getting cut in half.

[image: example cut off]

I do not want to set the `android:maxLines` attribute so that I can support multiple screen sizes.

I have also considered using...

```
int maxLines = (int) textView.getHeight() / textView.getLineHeight();
textView.setMaxLines(maxLines);
```

..., but this could cause an issue because [markup within the text can cause individual lines to be taller or shorter than this height](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineHeight()).

Edit: I could use a ScrollView here to prevent the cutting in half of the text, but I would rather this be a preview, with a button below for the user to click to view the entire text.

Comment: The TextView must be a fixed height, but you don't want to use maxLines so you can support multiple screen sizes? To me it seems a contradiction. Personally I would use maxLines, and provide different layouts/values of maxLines for different screen sizes.

Comment: I need the TextView to line up in a grid with an image next to it which will have a fixed height. I am okay with the text cutting off early, but don't want it to go past the image that it is next to, hence the fixed height of the TextView. The image will change from time to time thus the height will change, and a hard coded maxLines will not be sufficient.

Comment: Hey yiati...did you find any solution??

Comment: Not quite. I created a custom layout for each size, and manually made it stop by setting maxLines before it was cut off automatically. This is the solution that Ken Wolf suggested above which still does not fix the problem, BUT is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your TextView inside a ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/MyTextParent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/MyText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="TEXT"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This would be a viable solution, however I am trying to keep it from being a ScrollView, and rather a preview with a link below that will take the user to the entire text.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ellipsize manually, using `setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt where)`, and defining where you want the text to be cut off.