# Android linearlayouts not expanding as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I have this code below that creates a square with an image, textview and 2 image buttons.

It looks like this:

[image]

I want it so that the text is always in 1 line. The width of the square needs to expand so it includes the full text. In the image, the text gets cropped. The two little buttons (info and settings) needs to be in the corners of the square. Also there is another problem, the text is not vertically centered and it should be.

I can't quite get it to look right. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

```
public static LinearLayout createNodeWrapper(Activity context, Fish fish) {
    ImageView imageview = createImageView(context, fish);
    TextView nametv = createNameView(context, fish.getName());
    ImageButton info = createButton(context, R.drawable.ic_action_info);
    ImageButton settings = createButton(context, R.drawable.ic_action_settings);

    LinearLayout namewrapper = createNameWrapper(context);
    namewrapper.addView(info);
    namewrapper.addView(nametv);
    namewrapper.addView(settings);

    LinearLayout contentwrapper = createContentWrapper(context, fish);
    contentwrapper.addView(imageview);
    contentwrapper.addView(namewrapper);

    LinearLayout fullwrapper = createFullWrapper(context, fish);
    fullwrapper.addView(contentwrapper);

    return fullwrapper;
}

private static ImageView createImageView(Context context, Fish fish) {
    ImageView imageview = new ImageView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = fish.getImageParams();
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
    imageview.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    return imageview;
}

private static TextView createNameView(Context context, String name) {
    TextView nametv = new TextView(context);
    nametv.setText(name);
    nametv.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.node);
    nametv.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 10);
    nametv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    nametv.setSingleLine(true);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    textparams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    nametv.setLayoutParams(textparams);
    return nametv;
}

private static ImageButton createButton(Context context, int resId) {
    ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(context);
    imageButton.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imageparams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    imageButton.setLayoutParams(imageparams);
    imageButton.setBackgroundResource(resId);
    return imageButton;
}

private static LinearLayout createNameWrapper(Context context) {
    LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(context);
    wrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    wrapper.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    wrapper.setLayoutParams(params);
    return wrapper;
}

private static LinearLayout createContentWrapper(Context context, Fish fish) {
    LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(context);
    wrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    wrapper.setPadding(3, 0, 3, 3);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = fish.getParams();
    wrapper.setLayoutParams(params);
    wrapper.setMinimumWidth(MIN_NODE_WIDTH);
    return wrapper;
}

private static LinearLayout createFullWrapper(Context context, Fish fish) {
    LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(context);
    wrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category_bg);
    wrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = fish.getParams();
    params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    wrapper.setLayoutParams(params);
    return wrapper;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you use the android xml for defining your layouts?

Comment: I do this dynamically for many of them.

Answer (score 0):

For the text, try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2142968/2629065 it will scale down the text until it fits the parameters you give it.

You padded the top, which adds to the height of the item, offsetting the gravity alignment. Remove the top padding and use a margin, or pad the bottom.